# Will Siri work with 3rd party apps after update from iOS 9 to 10?

Tags: ios, siri, iphone

I want to purchase iPhone 6s having iOS 9. I will update from iOS 9 to 10 but I want to know if after updating the iOS version Siri work with 3rd party applications or not? Are there any changes in Siri features in iPhone 6s to iPhone 7? I want to work with 3rd party applications using Siri in iPhone 6s. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SiriKit, or third-party integration with Siri, is available on any device compatible with iOS 10. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_10):

> Siri is compatible with third-party app-specific requests, such as starting workouts apps, sending IMs, requesting the Lyft or Uber apps or to use payment functions.

Note that not all apps utilise SiriKit, and only those that do will work with Siri.

Comment: It means i can purchase iPhone 6s & then update to iOS v10 then use 3rd party applications. Is there any difference between Siri features in iPhone 6s or 7

Comment: @ShahinP Not as far as I know.

Comment: Is it compulsory to install Sirikit or it simply works after upgrade to iOS 10 to get 3rd party application features

Comment: @ShahinP SiriKit is automatically installed when upgrading to iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS 10 is backward capable with iOS so everything should work the same.

This year they even added full automatic migration and conversion of iOS 9 to iOS 10 code so apps should be updated in no time.

Apple support Iphones Generation 5 and upwards, but bare in mind Generation 8 is coming soon and thus support for Iphone 5 might phase out.
Still Gen 6 should be relevant at least two years to come.

Please correct me if I'm misinformed